# Dockerize Angular app which uses Python and Oracle as backend

Tags: python, angular, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to dockerize my angular app that calls backend database Oracle from my python app. Without docker, I'm able to ng serve my app on port 4201 and my backend runs on port 2232. All this works fine, but when I try to docerize it, I seem to get COR's error. I'm not sure what I am missing.

Python dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
ADD thomas.py /
CMD [ "python3", "./thomas.py" ]
```

Angular Dockerfile:

```
# Stage 1
FROM node:12.16.1-alpine as build-step
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build --prod
# Stage 2
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build-step /usr/src/app/dist/bim-angulardashboard/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Nginx.conf file:

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;

    gzip              on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_proxied      any;
    gzip_min_length   500;
    gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_types        text/plain text/xml text/css
                      text/comma-separated-values
                      text/javascript
                      application/x-javascript
                      application/atom+xml;


    # Configuration for the server
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

      location / {
          root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
          index  index.html;
          expires -1;
          default_type application/javascript;
          add_header Pragma "no-cache";
          add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
          try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
      }

      location /api {
            proxy_pass          http://<my_vm_server_name>:5000;
            proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      }
    }
}
```

Docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  python-app:
    build:
      context: ./docker/flask
      dockerfile: Dockerfile #this is your dockerfile
    container_name: python-app #docker container name
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /
    ports:
      - "5000:5000" #binding ports, external port : application listening port
    volumes:
      - ./in000031-batch_dashboard/docker/flask/:/var/www/html # after : its the location in the container OS
    networks:
      app-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.2
  angular-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile #this is your dockerfile
    container_name: angular-app #docker container name
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /
    ports:
      - "4201:80" #binding ports, external port : nginx listening port
    volumes:
      - ./in000031-batch_dashboard/:/var/www/html # after : its the location in the container OS
    networks:
      app-network:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.3
  

#Docker Networks
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
          - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
#Volumes
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

Kindly let me know if any of my config files are wrong or if you have a better solution? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you install the drivers necessary to connect to your oracle db in your docker image? Did you follow the steps listed at the site given at the end of the stacktrace?

Comment: I'd edit your question to either a) reflect the error shown in your stacktrace (Oracle DB connection error) and add the stacktrace as a code snippet rather than an image or b) show the error details for the CORS error that you are seeing

Comment: Error says you're missing a library... and your question doesn't mention anything about oracle libraries. We don't know what you have done or checked, you have to include that into your question.

Comment: @C.Nivs , I've added the COR's error screenshot now. And yes I've installed the necessary drivers for Oracle_cx on my Linux VM that I am using. Without docker, it connects to db and I see the output, but running it on docker I get the above errors.

Comment: You need the drivers installed in the container for them to be used, not the host

Comment: @C.Nivs, I tried looking for ways to install Oracle instant linux on docker, but haven't found a good solution yet. Would you be able to assist with either dockerfile or steps to run Oracle instant on docker?

Comment: @JamesZ ..Can you please assist me if the edited question helps now?

Comment: First attempt on google showed me this: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1

Comment: Yes, @James Z. I already looked into this and tried using this approach, but l realized there were some organization related restrictions due to which I had errors pop up. Thanks all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is connectivity issue with Python and Oracle DB. How Oracle db is installed ? Is it also docker service or hosted somewhere else ?

Make sure you are providing proper service name of Oracle db/ip address for database connection.

Comment: without docker I used the steps in [link](https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux) to install Oracle_cx and I was able to run my app fine. But when I run it on docker, should I again install Oracle_cx on docker before starting the containers?